# How to replace AVR _delay_ms() with timer

Tags: avr, atmega, timer, delay

Good day.

I need problem with replacing _delay_ms() bultin function with timer.

MCU: Atmega644@16Mhz

My code (simplified):

```
volatile uint32_t u32_timer1 = 0;

void InitTimer1()
{
    uint16_t u16_timer_ctc = 15999;
    
    /* CTC mode, clock divided by 1. */

    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS10);
        
    /* Load the high byte, then the low byte into the output compare register. */

    OCR1AH = HIBYTE(u16_timer_ctc);
        
    OCR1AL = LOBYTE(u16_timer_ctc);
        
    /* Start the timer 1 in CTC mode. */
        
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
}

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    /* Event to be executed every one millisecond. */
    
    u32_timer1++;
}

void DelayInMilliseconds(uint32_t NeeededDelay)
{
     //Currently call _delay_ms() function, but I want replace with timer1.

    _delay_ms(NeededDelay);
}

int main()
{
         InitTimer1();

         while(1)
         {
                 SomeCodePlaceholder();
                 DelayInMilliseconds(300);
                 SomeCodePlaceholder();
                 DelayInMilliseconds(50);
                 //ETC....
          }
}
```

**I need replace code in function DelayInMilliseconds()using timer 1, not _delay_us().**

EDIT: My approach using timer 1:

```
uint32_t u32_milliseconds_present = 0;

uint32_t u32_milliseconds_past = 0;

void DelayInMilliseconds(uint32_t u32_delay)
{
    u32_milliseconds_present = u32_timer1;
    
    //NOW WE HAVE MS ELAPSED, BUT WHATS NEXT?
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your reason for making this change?  Unless you change your program structure, there's limited reason to do so.  You may gain more time accuracy though you won't be able to do other things in the meantime.  You might look at how Arduino for example sets up a millisecond timer interrupt which enables user code to wait until so many of those ticks have elapsed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thank for comment, yes I study Arduino code, but problem remain same. At all examples I saw, authors uses one delay in main loop, but I need versatile function with variable delay argument

Comment: So wait until the millisecond counter has been incremented a suitable number of times.  And be sure to subtract before comparing, so that the way you do so is overflow safe.  Again you could learn a lot from the Arduino realm as this is typically what they do with their similar millis() capability which should near directly port to your situation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I trying this approach, but how calling this?